# What measure word should I use when I have two nouns with different measure words?

Tags: usage, measure-word

If someone asks me:

你在动物园看了几（___）老虎和马呀？

Choose the correct answer:

a) 个
b) 只
c) 匹
d) other ______
e) all of the above
f) none of the above
g) screw Chinese, I'm going to study Klingon

Thanx!

Comment: Quick answer: In this case Chinese don't ask like that. Simply you can avoid measure words as 你在動物園看了多少老虎和馬呀？

Answer (score 2):

In this case, a more correct way would be:

> 你在动物园看了几只老虎和几匹马呀？

or

> 你在动物园看了多少只老虎，多少匹马？

In colloquial speech, it might be ok to say:

> 你在动物园看了多少个老虎和马呀？

or

> 你在动物园看了几个老虎和马呀？

Answer (score 1):

The correct classifier for 老虎 (tiger) is 头

The correct classifier for 斑马 (zebra) is 匹 (*I don't think people need to go to the zoo to see horses)*

> 你在动物园看了多少(头)老虎和多少(匹)斑马呀？

~

> In Cantonese, 隻/只 is the right classifier for both 老虎 and 斑马
>
> 你喺動物園睇咗幾多(隻)老虎同斑馬呀？

Comment: Yeah, horses are boring, but the girls that ride them ......

Comment: Horse-drawn vehicles are disallowed in most cities in China. So I believe for people who live in a city, go to the zoo should be the best choice to see horses.

Answer (score 1):

In colloquial, I would totally say 你在动物园看了几只老虎和马呀？ It's not grammatically right, but I think we should follow the closest noun.  To me, 个 is wrong for animals in any event.

I listen to this song grown up:

```
两只老虎，两只老虎
跑得快，跑得快
一只没有耳朵，一只没有尾巴
真奇怪，真奇怪
```

I can't imagine 两个老虎..

You can listen to it on youtube https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=orJ2tGFr2S0

Answer (score 0):

a) 个 is the right answer to me. I have never studied Chinese, but can speak basic Cantonese..and this is what we would say in that case....hope this will help you

Comment: 个 is not the right classifier for either 老虎 or 马

Answer (score 0):

I would use 只：

你在动物园看见了几只老虎和斑马呀？

But if it is not a question:

我昨天在动物园看到了老虎、狮子、斑马还有孔雀。

Answer (score 0):

in this ques, you can't use 個，never use 個 on animal

隻 is fine, 隻 can use on all the animal

匹 is a special quantify, almost use for horse

but in this situation, ask: "How many"(多少)lion and horse did you see in the zoo

你在动物园看了几（___）老虎和马呀？ >>

你在動物園看到"多少"老虎和馬啊？ will be more properly(but is all correct)

In Chinese you can separate them all

你們看到幾隻雞？幾隻鴨？幾隻兔子還有幾隻狗啊？

how many...,how many...,how many...,and how many...?did you see?

(sorry I can only type only traditional chinese)